# set the permissions on all the files and folders within a directory (CentOS 7.0 )

Tags: file-permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux, centos-7

I kind of new to Linux/Centos world, is there any way to set the permissions on all the files and folders within a directory. I know chmod 777 will set permissions on the directory, but if it already has contents, I need to know how to set that too. In windows, you propagate the permission down, must be a way to do that in Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a folder and it has content in it so i want to change it's permission but when i do it only change the permission for the main directory not the content inside it, and also when i create new file the new file picks up old permission instead of newly assign permissions

Comment: chmod 777 -R directory/ Resolved the issue.

Comment: Note that using 777 will not only set read, write, and execute permission for everyone, but will also remove any sticky/setuid/etc. bits on any files. And those octal codes are hardly easy to remember/follow. I don'y understand why people don't use symbolic codes instead: e.g. to add **r**ead, **w**rite, and e**x**ecute permission for **a**ll (without removing any other permissions)), just use `a+rwx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chmod` with the  `-R` (short for recursive) flag:

```shell
chmod 777 -R some_directory
```